# jquery function does not invoked

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts

I have following html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../themes/icon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#test').treegrid({
            iconCls:'icon-save',
            width:1500,
            height:350,
            nowrap: false,
            rownumbers: true,
            animate:true,
            collapsible:true,
        url:'jsondata.jsp',
            idField:'job',
            treeField:'job',
            columns:[[
                             {field:'job',title:'Job',width:200,
                    formatter:function(value){
                        return '<span style="color:red">'+value+'</span>';
                    }
                },
                {field:'desc',title:'Description',width:250},
                {field:'start_date',title:'Start date',width:150,rowspan:2},
                {field:'end_date',title:'End Date',width:250,rowspan:2},
                {field:'progress',title:'Progress',width:300,rowspan:2,
                    formatter:function(value){
                    alert(value);
                        if (value){
                            var s = '<div style="width:100%;background:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc">' +
                                    '<div style="width:' + value + '%;background:red">' + value + '%' + '</div>'
                                    '</div>';
                            alert(s);
                            return s;
                        } else {
                            return '';
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]],
            onBeforeLoad:function(row,param){
                if (row){
                    alert("subdata.json called");
                    $(this).treegrid('options').url = 'jsondata.jsp';
                } else {
                    alert("data.json called");
                    $(this).treegrid('options').url = 'jsondata.jsp';
                }
            },
            onContextMenu: function(e,row){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).treegrid('unselectAll');
                $(this).treegrid('select', row.job);
                $('#mm').menu('show', {
                    left: e.pageX,
                    top: e.pageY
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function reload(){
        var node = $('#test').treegrid('getSelected');
        if (node){
            $('#test').treegrid('reload', node.job);
        } else {
            $('#test').treegrid('reload');
        }
    }
    function collapse(){
        var node = $('#test').treegrid('getSelected');
        if (node){
            $('#test').treegrid('collapse', node.job);
        }
    }
    function expand(){
        var node = $('#test').treegrid('getSelected');
        if (node){
            $('#test').treegrid('expand', node.job);
        }
    }
    function collapseAll(){
        var node = $('#test').treegrid('getSelected');
        if (node){
            $('#test').treegrid('collapseAll', node.job);
        } else {
            $('#test').treegrid('collapseAll');
        }
    }
    function expandAll(){
        var node = $('#test').treegrid('getSelected');
        if (node){
            $('#test').treegrid('expandAll', node.job);
        } else {
            $('#test').treegrid('expandAll');
        }
    }
    var jobIndex = 1000;
    function append(){
        jobIndex++;
        var data = [{
            job: 'job'+jobIndex,
            desc: 'desc'+jobIndex,
            start_date: '12/28/2012',
            end_date: '12/30/2012',
            progress: '80'
        }];
        var node = $('#test').treegrid('getSelected');
        $('#test').treegrid('append', {
            parent: (node?node.job:null),
            data: data
        });
    }
    function remove(){
        var node = $('#test').treegrid('getSelected');
        if (node){
            $('#test').treegrid('remove', node.job);
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<div style="margin:10px 0;">
    <a href="#" onclick="reload()">Reload</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="collapse()">Collapse</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="expand()">Expand</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="collapseAll()">CollapseAll</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="expandAll()">ExpandAll</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="append()">Append</a>
</div>

<table id="test"></table>

<div id="mm" class="easyui-menu" style="width:120px;">
    <div onclick="append()">Append</div>
    <div onclick="remove()">Remove</div>
</div>
```

When i run this file directly, it runs fine, i.e it invokes jsondata.jsp file, from which i am returning json data.

But when i call this through struts action using mapping.findForward it only displays the hyperlinks(reload,collapse..) and does not invoke $(function(){}. What to do?

Comment: First, I'd recommend against relative links to JS/CSS/etc. Second, is anything in the JS console? Do the proper scripts show up in your browser's development tools? My first guess without any real information is that your JS isn't getting loaded.

Comment: @Christoph Give me a break. How are absolute paths, the paths guaranteed to work regardless of how an HTML fragment is used, "worse"? There's a known mechanism to get the path of a file in a Java web app, and it should be used.

Comment: well, I guess I should have looked at the tags, I ignored the Java tags - My bad;-D